# Calling a method in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I can't figure out how to call `public int sumR(int n)`. Any help?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       sumR();
    }


public static int sumR(int n) {

    Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num;
    num = scannerObject.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");


       if (n==1)
        return 1;
       else 
        return (n + sumR(n-1));

        }
    }
```

Comment: sumR(int n) requires an integer, so call it with an integer, i.e. sumR(5);

Answer (score 0):

You need a number in the calling method. Like sumR(4); or sumR(i); First off, the scanner needs to be in the main method to read in user input.

```
     Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num;
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        num = scannerObject.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    sumR(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the int n when you call the function. In your main function, add this:

```
int num = 5; \\assign whatever value you need before calling the function with it.
sumR(num);
```

Hope it helps.